# Pattern Matching in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have this rule:

```
andR( conj(C,D) ).
```

So I want it to match with items such as `conj(x,y)` which is fine.  However, how do you get it to match with something more complicated like (i.e. a conjunction again but not of two atoms):

```
andR( conj(not(conj(not(a),c)),c),not(a) ).
```

because Prolog doesn't match with this with my `andR/1` predicate because it interprets a comma and thinks that I've tried calling a /1 predicate with 2 paramaters.

Any ideas guys?  This has puzzled me for a while now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need an additional `conj` surrounding the top level `conj` and `not`?

Comment: Hey, Oh how stupid of me, yes the statement was wrong!  Thank you :).